# How to interpret estimated coefficient of ordered logit regression which has a negative value

Tags: regression, spss, logit, ordered-logit

What is the interpretation of the negative estimate ($b$ value) in an ordered logit regression?

That is, an "increase of one unit in the independent variable results in an increase or decrease of the odds ratio of the dependent variable..."

For context, my exponentiated $b$ value is 0.869 for feed cost (independent variable) and the dependent variable is income in poultry and it is in ordinal level of measurement.

Answer (score 1):

Negative beta would indicate inverse relationship, i.e increase in feed cost leads to decrease in income in poultry.

Comment: increase one unit in feed cost leads to decrease the income in the odds ratio of 0.869 . Is the interpretation correct?

Comment: Yes, if odds ratio is less than one it indicates an inverse relationship.